# Problem targeting a component to set style

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a custom component that uses a mat-checkbox. And i want to only change the bqckground for that component but i don't have much luck.

My Template code is below

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{labelText}}</mat-label>
    <mat-select class="select" #select [multiple]="multiselect" [formControl]="selectField" >
      <div class="select-all">
          <mat-checkbox *ngIf="multiselect" [(ngModel)]="allSelected"
                         class="mat-check-all"
                          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                          [indeterminate]="isIndeterminate()"
                          [checked]="isChecked()" 
                          (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                          (change)="toggleAllSelection($event)">{{text}}</mat-checkbox>
      </div>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item[idField]">
        {{item[fieldName]}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

i tried the following with no luck

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
.mat-check-all .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
.select-all .mat-check-all .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
.select .select-all .mat-check-all .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
::ng-deep .select .select-all .mat-check-all .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
```

neither of the above made any difference. When i used

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
```

it changed the color for my checkbox but also for any other checkbox on the form. So how can i limit the change to the checkbox in my componenet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your above template code you can just simply set the color for your custom component via

```
::ng-deep
  .select-all
  .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent
  .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: rgb(224, 198, 28) !important;
}
```

You can verify in the forked StackBlitz [Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yyrskd?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a class to the form you're using or wrap it with a div with the class then use `::ng-deep`
like this

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form" class="my-custom-form">
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{labelText}}</mat-label>
    <mat-select class="select" #select [multiple]="multiselect" [formControl]="selectField" >
      <div class="select-all">
          <mat-checkbox *ngIf="multiselect" [(ngModel)]="allSelected"
                         class="mat-check-all"
                          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                          [indeterminate]="isIndeterminate()"
                          [checked]="isChecked()" 
                          (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                          (change)="toggleAllSelection($event)">{{text}}</mat-checkbox>
      </div>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item[idField]">
        {{item[fieldName]}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

```
.my-custom-form ::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
```

this will limit the effect of ng-deep to this form only

Comment: Tried and it did not work..

Comment: here is a sample in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csg267?file=src/app/mat-select/mat-select.component.css

Answer (score 0):

`ng-deep` is deprecated, and was never necessary. Angular uses view encapsulation, so any css you put in the component's css file will not affect other components, such as the mat-checkbox, by default.

You can put the css in a global file like `styles.css` and use a specific selector, I'd recommend prepending the component name, or simply adding an id:

**In styles.css or another global css file**

```css
my-component-tag .select .select-all .mat-check-all .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);
  }
```

You can create a new global style file and add it to the `styles` array in `angular.json` if you want. Or you can simply import it into `styles.scss` if you're using scss.

**OR**

You can disable view encapsulation for the component, which will cause all css in that component's css file to become global:

**In the component.ts file**

```js
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

Comment: So can you explain the **my-component-tag ** ? And i assume its used to limit the use of the class to that component

Comment: Yes exactly, it's the css selector / html tag for that component, I don't know what the name of your component is so I put that. You could also just use a unique class name or id. Just keep in mind you may need to increase specificity to override any other css. If you inspect the element and see your css is greyed out, you know you have selected the element but the specificity is too low.

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer with ng-deep and !important, both of those are quick hacks and should really be avoided. ng-deep will be removed in a later angular version as well. It's really just what people do when they're not sure how css and view encapsulation work.

Answer (score -1):

for changing background of label you can use this code

```
    .mat-checkbox-label{ background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);}
```

and for changing check mark background this :

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background{ background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);}
```

and you have to add this classes to main style file which is defined in angular.json file in the "styles" key , it seems like this :

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Comment: i know how i can change the background but i don't want to change on all of my checkboxes

Comment: you can add class to the  check box and change class to this  .someclass .mat-checkbox-label{ background-color: rgb(49, 201, 11);} and it should add to main style class because local css file which is used in component will not affect on material components

Comment: if you read my original question then you would see that that's the problem, id does not work, thats why you use ::ng-deep so it effects but it will effect all